# A poset with small "cycles"

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets, lattice-theory

(A followup to [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40348/proving-that-a-poset-is-a-lattice).)

I noticed the following curious property of a poset (which I strongly believe to be a lattice, I'm still trying to prove that…):

Suppose that $z$ is covered by $x$ and $y$.  Then there is a common upper bound $w$ of $x$ and $y$ such that either

- $w$ covers both $x$ and $y$, or
- $w$ covers either $x$ or $y$  (say $y$), and the other element is separated from $w$ by exactly one more element (say $a$).

(There is [an example poset](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512115725/http://service.ifam.uni-hannover.de/%7Erubey/poset.pdf), computed using sage-combinat and dot2tex.)

Using ASCII art, all relations are covering:

```
    w                 w 
   / \               / \
  x   y      or     a   |
   \ /              |   |
    z               x   y
                     \ /
                      z
```

Does this property have some name?  Could it be helpful for proving that the poset is a lattice?

Although it's rather trivial, let us note that there are non-lattices having this property:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
  |\ /|
  |/ \|
  4   5
   \ /
    6
```

Hm, could it be that such a poset (i.e., with restricted cycle lengths) and with no occurrences of

```
  a   b            a    d
  |\ /|     and    |\  /|
  |/ \|            b \/ |
  c   d            | /\ |
                   c    e
```

is a lattice...?  No, this is not the case:

```
      1
     /|\
    / | \
   /  |  \
  2   3   4
  |\ / \ /|
  |/ \ / \|
  5   6   7
   \ / \ /
    8   9
     \ /
      0
```

Comment: Given an upper bound $s$ of $x$ and $y$ (i.e., $x \le s$ and $y \le s$), do you also find a $w \le s$ with the described properties whenever $x$ and $y$ cover a common element $z$?

Comment: Well, no... (assuming that you mean $w$ should also be an upper bound of $x$ and $y$)

Comment: Yes, I was asking about the fact whether your "curious property" holds also in intervals. Is your $w$ unique for given $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I understand your question.  I believe (but cannot prove yet) that $w$ is the join of $x$ and $y$, but there are other upper bounds of $x$ and $y$, too.  Also, $z$ can have other covering elements beside $x$ and $y$.  Finally, one can show that the posets always have a minimal and a maximal element.

Comment: OK, I try to phrase both questions again: (Q1) Given $z, x, y, s$ in your poset such that (a) $x \le s$ and (b) $y \le s$ and (c) $x$ covers $z$ and (d) $y$ covers $z$, does there exist a $w \le s$ such that either (x) $w$ covers $x$ and $w$ covers an element covering $y$ or (y) $w$ covers $y$ and $w$ covers an element covering $x$ or (z) $w$ covers both $x$ and $y$ holds? (Q2) Is the $w$ whose existence was asked for in (Q1) unique? As far as I checked it, the for your example poset both questions should be answered with yes. If either answer is no, I doubt your property will imply lattice.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble of rephrasing!  No, I cannot (yet) prove that such a $w$ exists, given $s$.  (Since I believe that my poset is a lattice, I better also believe that the answers to both Q1 and Q2 are "yes": given $z$,$x$,$y$ I can construct $w$. The only missing bit is to show that $w$ is less than all other upper bounds of $x$ and $y$...)

Comment: Can you already prove that $w$ is unique (for $s = $ the maximal element of the poset)?

Comment: Yes.  And, I should have mentioned, the construction can be dualised, i.e. if $a$ and $b$ are both covered by $c$, then I can construct a lower bound, dual to the above.

Comment: I already guessed that the dual property holds because of your reference to your older question. But I couldn't get anything out of it.

Comment: As $w$ is unique, I'd focus on showing that you can find it even below a given upper bound $s$ of $x$ and $y$. Any chance to prove it? Thanks to David's answer to your other question, you should be done then.

Comment: This behaviour would be consistent with the poset having a left modular chain.  (This property is not enough to guarantee that the poset has a left modular chain, but it suggests that the posets you want might have that property.)  See Peter McNamara and Hugh Thomas, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211126.  

Comment: @Hugh: although having a left modular chain was a very promising idea, very unfortunately it turned out not to be the case (in general)...

Comment: I think I have an example of one of your posets that is not shellable (in the non-pure sense).  That would rule out some properties your posets could have, but not speak to whether they are lattices.  My example has unique minimal and maximal elements $\hat{0}$ and $\hat{1}$, as well as three atoms called $x,y,z$ and three coatoms which are the joins of the three pairs of atoms, and three further intermediate elements $x',y',z'$ where $x\prec x'\prec x\vee y$ and $y\prec y'\prec y\vee z$ and $z\prec z'\prec z\vee x$.   In other words, it's the 1-skeleton of a 3-ball with 6 pentagonal 2-cells.

Comment: It's been long enough that you've probably either solved the problem or lost interest, but since no one else has mentioned it, I'll point out that the property you mention is _almost_ that of semimodularity.  That is, if you require the diamond and disallow the pentagon (in your two allowed diagrams given two elements covering a common element) it is exactly semimodularity.  Semimodularity is well-studied -- see e.g. the book by Manfred Stern.